# MacBook Pro Delete functioning as forward-delete instead of backspace?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

A friend has a recent model MacBook Pro and has recently switched to an external Mac keyboard with both delete keys: <kbd>Delete</kbd> (backspace) and <kbd>⌦</kbd> (forward-delete). However, two days ago the built-in MacBook keyboard's <kbd>Delete</kbd> has changed its default function to forward-delete instead of backspace.

As far as they can tell, the function key (which normally modifies Delete to forward-delete) is not stuck or faulty, and pressing it does not modify the key's behaviour. They haven't installed any third-party software to modify the key's default behaviour.

Has anyone else seen this, and know how to fix it? I haven't confirmed this but given the problem started a couple of days ago and they have installed a recent update, I'm guessing they have macOS 12.3 - which introduces Universal Control allowing a keyboard to work with both a Mac and iPad, so that could be related?

Another factor: though the new Mac keyboard was working fine until a couple of days ago, they did switch from previously using a Windows external keyboard before that.